# how to automatically zoom map when animated marker is 1 km from destination

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i'm working with google maps v3 animations and i have a question

this is my example http://gidzior.net/map/v3_animate_marker_directions.html (i'm using placeholder in the input), GM code is from here

how to automatically zoom map when animated marker is 1 km from destination ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new global variable `zoomed`
Add the following into `function animate(d)`:

```
if (d>eol-1000 && zoomed!=true) {
  map.setZoom(14); // or whatever value
  zoomed=true;
}
```

The reason to use a simple flag and not test `map.getZoom()` is because that function call will be slower so we don't want to call `getZoom()` with every animation step. Note that performing the zoom may be problematic if tiles need to be loaded while the animation is continuing.

Comment: one question - zoom is working but only once, when i typy another address the second animation is without zoom, how i can fix it ?

Comment: After `map.fitBounds(bounds)` when you show the route, add the line `zoomed=false` to reset it.